# Using discriminator with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to create a discriminator column. This column would hold one of the many statuses available. Like my code will show, each status has a name as well as a background color. Each status shares the same base class.

Here is my code:

```
public class Item
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Status ItemStatus { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Status
{
    private readonly int _id;
    public static readonly Status Foo = new FooStatus(1);
    public static readonly Status Bar = new BarStatus(2);

    public Status()
    {

    }

    protected Status(int id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }

    public virtual int Id { get { return _id; } }
    public abstract string Name { get; }
    public abstract string BackgroundColor { get; }
}

public class FooStatus : Status
{
    public FooStatus()
    {

    }

    public FooStatus(int id)
        : base(id)
    {

    }

    public override string Name
    {
        get { return "Foo Status"; }
    }

    public override string BackgroundColor
    {
        get { return "White"; }
    }
}

public class BarStatus : Status
{
    public BarStatus()
    {

    }

    public BarStatus(int id)
        : base(id)
    {

    }

    public override string Name
    {
        get { return "Bar Status"; }
    }

    public override string BackgroundColor
    {
        get { return "Black"; }
    }
}
```

And here is my mapping:

```
public class ItemMap : ClassMap<Item>
{
    public ItemMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();

        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn<int>("ItemStatus", 0).AlwaysSelectWithValue();
    }
}
```

Essentially, what I'd like is that if I set `ItemStatus` to `Status.Foo` then the `ItemStatus` column would have a value of 1. What I have now doesn't throw any exceptions, but it always inserts `ItemStatus` as `0`.

This is the inserting code I'm using:

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var item = new Item
    {
        ItemStatus = Status.Foo
    };
    session.Save(item);
    transaction.Commit();

    var firstItem = session.Get<Item>(1);
    Console.WriteLine(firstItem.ItemStatus.Name);
}
```

Where can I read up on this topic using FNH?

Before anyone suggests be to check on Google I did search several things but nowhere can I find a full example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `SubclassMap` would look something like this:

```
public class FooStatusMap : SubclassMap<FooStatus>
{
    public FooStatusMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue(1);
    }
}
```

This is called "table-per-class-hierarchy," and you're right it doesn't look like there are many resources on it out there.

I *believe* if you don't call `DiscriminatorValue` in a `SubclassMap`, NHibernate attempts to discriminate by looking at the name of the subclass being mapped and seeing if it matches up with the value in the discriminator column.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. When I create a subclass map for each status NHibernate still inserts `0` as my `ItemStatus`. This must be due to the fact that I set the `baseClassDiscriminator` to 0. However, if I remove the `baseClassDiscriminator` NHibernate throws exception "Could not format discriminator value to SQL string of entity NHibernateDiscriminator.Domain.Item" when building my configuration.

Comment: @User: Interesting. I will set up this mapping and see if I can duplicate it.

Comment: @User: In the database, is the datatype an integer?

Comment: The database data type is an integer. Think it gets set by using `DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn*<int>*`

Comment: @User: Actually, looking over your code again you need to define a mapping for the base `Status` type, and put the `DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn` code there (not in ItemMap). Then define a subclass map for each sub type.

Comment: Ah, it seems like I'm getting there. What do you map `ItemStatus` as in the `Item` mapping?

Comment: Hmm--Is there a separate table for `Status`? Or is it included in the `Item` table?

Comment: Mapping it as a foreign key worked. Thank you very much for your help. :D

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt write submaps for all the subclasses you can just do this instead

```
public class FooMap: ClassMap<T>
{
//other mapping
DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("DiscriminatorColumn")
.SubClass<Foo1>(m => { })
.SubClass<Foo2>(m => { })
.SubClass<Foo3>(m => { });
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: My initial implementation was using this approach, but it's obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to the Discriminator column having the class names of the derived classes, you can implement this via automapping.

In your session factory:

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
    var cfg = new MyMappingConfiguration();
    return Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("MyConnectionKey")).FormatSql().ShowSql()
            )
    .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Status>(cfg)
    .IncludeBase<Status>()
    .Conventions.Add<PrimaryKeyConvention>()))
    .BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

Then add the MyMappingConfiguration override:

```
public class MappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool IsId(Member member)
    {
        return member.Name == member.DeclaringType.Name + "Id";
    }

    public override bool IsDiscriminated(Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Hope that h