# using class in where-condition of HQL-Query

Tags: nhibernate, hql, joined-subclass

I have a Entity Contact which has three joined-subclass (Person, Company, Branch).
When I do a select-query on Contact where I should only get the Person's, Companies or Branches, I can do

> select from Contact a where a.class = Person

this is working correct in the case of Person and Branch. But because Branch is himself referencing Company (with CompanyId), and when I do now

> select from Contact a where a.class = Company

it will replace Company with CompanyId (from the Branch-Entity).

Does someone have an Idea, how I can prevent HQL from replacing the class-value with a real column?

Comment: Perhaps you could use a discriminator instead for your project? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887168/using-discriminator-with-fluent-nhibernate) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708969/query-by-discriminator-in-nhibernate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use fully qualified name of the class (including the namespace):

```
select from Contact a where a.class = Your.Namespace.Company
```

This should help NHibernate to differentiate class name from property name.